# Tilemap mesh issue with z, -z axis

Tags: unity, rendering, tilemap, mesh

I don't understand why the created mesh is upside down if z ( `z*tileSize` ) is positive, the mesh is then rendered with the texture looking down. With "-z", the mesh texture is looking up correctly, but it then starts at 0,0,0 and follows his path to the negative values, which I don't want. (I would like the mesh to create tiles in the X/Z axis, not in the X/-Z axis).

Would you know how to fix this? Here is the method to create the mesh : (if I switch the normals to `-Vector3.up`, the plane texture is still looking down, and it becomes black.)

```
public void BuildMesh() {
        int numTiles = size_x * size_z;
        int numTris = numTiles * 2;

        int vsize_x = size_x + 1;
        int vsize_z = size_z + 1;
        int numVerts = vsize_x * vsize_z;

        // Generate the mesh data
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[ numVerts ];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[numVerts];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[numVerts];

        int[] triangles = new int[ numTris * 3 ];

        int x, z;
        for(z=0; z < vsize_z; z++) {
            for(x=0; x < vsize_x; x++) {
//HERE
                vertices[ z * vsize_x + x ] = new Vector3( x*tileSize, 0, -z*tileSize );
                normals[ z * vsize_x + x ] = Vector3.up;
                uv[ z * vsize_x + x ] = new Vector2( (float)x / size_x, 1f - (float)z / size_z );
            }
        }

        for(z=0; z < size_z; z++) {
            for(x=0; x < size_x; x++) {
                int squareIndex = z * size_x + x;
                int triOffset = squareIndex * 6;
                triangles[triOffset + 0] = z * vsize_x + x +           0;
                triangles[triOffset + 1] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;
                triangles[triOffset + 2] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 0;

                triangles[triOffset + 3] = z * vsize_x + x +           0;
                triangles[triOffset + 4] = z * vsize_x + x +           1;
                triangles[triOffset + 5] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you started this question in the middle. What mesh is upside down?

Comment: The mesh built with BuildMesh is a plane with a created texture. When z is positive, the texture is facing down, so it is visible if the camera is below the mesh. If z is negative, it works fine, but then the mesh is using the X/-Z axis.